# Make variable the name of a list? Python

Tags: python, list, variables

I want each variable put into this function to then become the name of its own list.

```
def listy(x, insert):
    listend = isinstance(x, list)
    if listend:
        x.append(insert)
    else:
        x = []
        x.append(insert)
    print(x)

listy("xyz", "neutral")
listy("xyz", "happy")
```

When I do this, though, it overwrites the previous list (ends up with the list just reading "happy" instead of "neutral", "happy"). How do I get it to append if that word is already the name of a list?

Comment: isinstance is not turning it into a list. It's returning a boolean. Then your creating a list called x since it returns False then appending insert.

Comment: Do you want to create a variable `xyz` on a global context?

Comment: Dictionaries. This is what dictionaries are for.

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Comment: @BuddyBobIII Makes sense. I tried to reverse the if/else, but now I'm getting an AttributeError for str not having list

Answer (score 0):

Here this works for the example you gave. It uses dictionaries.

```
def listy(x, insert):
    varName[x].append(insert)
    return varName
varName = {"xyz":[]}
x = listy("xyz", "neutral")
y=listy("xyz", "happy")
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

> it overwrites the previous list ..

The previous list is not overwritten. The list created inside the function `listy` is auto destroyed by garbage collector. You are simply creating a new temporary list in second function call `listy("xyz", "happy")`, which will be destroted again. You need to put `x` in global context.

You can rewrite the function this way:

```
def listy(x, insert):
    listend = isinstance(x, list)
    if listend:
        x.append(insert)
    else:
        x = []
        x.append(insert)
    print(x)
    return x

x = listy("xyz", "neutral")
x = listy(x, "happy")
```

You seem to have confusion about references and objects. In python, everything is an object. A name like `x` is just a reference to an object. There is no way `x` in the second function call can refer to `["neutral"]` created and destroyed in the first function call.